# If total score is 0, don't insert

Tags: php, codeigniter

When adding scores for students, I would like those with a total score of 0 not to be inserted into the database at all.
I will like to first get the sum total of `get_ca1 + get_ca2 + get_ca3 + get_ca4 + get_ca5 + get_ca6  + get_exam`
then if the total is 0, don't insert.

This is the original code

```
 $array = array(
'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
'attendence' => $attendance,
'get_ca1' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'get_ca2' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca2_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'get_ca3' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca3_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'get_ca4' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca4_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'get_ca5' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca5_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'get_ca6' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca6_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'get_exam' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_exam_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'rem1' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_rem1_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'rem2' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_rem2_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'note' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_note_' . $exam_group_student_value),
);
  $insert_array[] = $array;
 }
}

  $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);
$array = array('status' => '1', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
            echo json_encode($array);          
        }
```

model

```
 public function add_result($insert_array)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start(); # Starting Transaction
        $this->db->trans_strict(false); # See Note 01. If you wish can remove as well
        if (!empty($insert_array)) {
            foreach ($insert_array as $student_key => $student_value) {
                $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'];
                $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id'];
                $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id']);
                $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id', $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id']);
                $q = $this->db->get('exam_group_exam_results');
                if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $update_result = $q->row();
                    $this->db->where('id', $update_result->id);
                    $this->db->update('exam_group_exam_results', $student_value);
                } else {
                    $this->db->insert('exam_group_exam_results', $student_value);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is what I've tried so far.

```
$cal1 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal2 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca2_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal3 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca3_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal4 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca4_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal5 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca5_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal6 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca6_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$exam = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_exam_' . $exam_group_student_value);

$total = $cal1 + $cal2 + $cal3 + $cal4 + $cal5 + $cal6 + $exam;

 if ($total > 0) {
$array = array(
'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
'attendence'                             => $attendance,
'get_ca1' => $cal1,
'get_ca2' => $cal2,
'get_ca3' => $cal3,
'get_ca4' => $cal4,
'get_ca5' => $cal5,
'get_ca6' => $cal6,
'get_exam' => $exam,
'rem1' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_rem1_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'rem2' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_rem2_' . $exam_group_student_value),
'note' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_note_' . $exam_group_student_value),
);
$insert_array[] = $array;
 }
  }
   }          
 $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);

$array = array('status' => '1', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
            echo json_encode($array);
        }
    }
```

I'm encountering a lot of problems with what I've tried so far

1. If there are blank fields, the form is not submitted
2. The form is only submitted when all students' fields have an input including zeroes

Comment: If the form data does not even get submitted at all, that sounds like there is client-side validation involved?